# How to enforce a unique combination of two similar fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, field

I have a set of points, defined by an id, and a database table which defines a **connection** between those points:

[point1, point2]

Now I can enforce that permutations of point1 and point2 are unique. So there's only 1 entry where *point1 = x* and *point2 = y*. But I want unique combinations, meaning that if there's a entry with *point1 = x* and *point2 = y*, it shouldn't be possible to get an entry with *point1 = y* and *point2 = x*.

Is it possible to configure the table for this or do I have to enforce this through code?

Comment: How is (x,y) the same as (y,x)?

Comment: are you using `auto increment`? in the table fields or are these random values?

Comment: @Vaughn: point ids are defined in another table, and are auto_incremented. point1 != point2.

Comment: @AJ: having an apple and a pear means I also have a pear and an apple.

Comment: @Clavus - I don't understand your fruit analogy.  (x,y) refers to a specific coordinate on a Cartesian plane. Note that (x,y) is equal to (y,x) only if (IFF) x=y.

Comment: @AJ: no the fruit analogy is correct in this case and the plane point is quite far from the idea of permutations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation On the plane the analogy maybe the folded plane about the line x=y, that is (x,y) is equal (y,x) for x!=y.

Answer (score 1):

This structure should work for you maybe?

**CORRECT**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `points`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `points` (
  `point1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `point2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `point1_point2_ux` (`point1`,`point2`),
  UNIQUE KEY `point2_point1_ux` (`point2`,`point1`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Triggers `points`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `testpoints`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `testpoints` BEFORE INSERT ON `points`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE num INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE point INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;

  SELECT count(*) INTO num FROM points WHERE point2 = NEW.point1 AND point1 = NEW.point2;

  IF(num>0) THEN
    SET point = NEW.point1;
    SET NEW.point1 = NEW.point2;
    SET NEW.point2 = point;
  END IF;

  END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent the (x,y) = (y,x) condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this with a combination of

1. a unique index on `(point1, point2)`
2. a trigger to enforce `point1 <= point2` (i.e., reverse the two values in the trigger if they violate that condition).

Comment: Hm, reading up on MySQL triggers. Seems to be what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest search for that combo like

`SELECT id WHERE pointx = 'value' AND pointy = 'value';` look for that combo.

`$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);`

`if($numrows !> 0){
    //do what ever with the points.
}`

Answer (score 0):

This trigger will do the job:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `db`.`on_points_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `db`.`points`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE num_reg INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM points WHERE 
    (p1 = new.p1 AND p2 = new.p2) OR (p1 = new.p2 AND p2 = new.p1)  INTO num_reg;
    IF(num_reg != 0) THEN
        CALL my_non_existant_procedure();
    END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I just test if there's a combination of the values you're trying to insert by counting the number of records that are returned by the condition `(p1 = new.p1 AND p2 = new.p2) OR (p1 = new.p2 AND p2 = new.p1)`, and if that number is different from 0 I call a non-existant procedure to make the trigger fail and avoid the insertion of the new record.